# bash array into string pattern

Tags: arrays, bash

How do I change a bash array into a string with this pattern? Let's say I have `arr=(a b c d)` and I want to change to this pattern
`'a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd'` with the white space in between.

PS-I figured out this pattern `'a'+'b'+'c'+'d'` but not sure how to put `" + "` instead of just `"+"` in between.

Answer (score 1):

In pure `bash` without resorting to an external command and without creating a subshell, using `bash` built-in `printf`'s implicit loop with `-v` option (which assigns the output to the variable rather than printing it):

```
printf -v str " + '%s'" "${arr[@]}"
str=${str:3} # to strip off leading ' + '
echo "$str"
```

This will also work with array elements containing blank characters (try with `arr=(a b c d "x y")` ). This solution assumes `arr` is not an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(a b c d)
str="${arr[@]}"
str=${str// / + } # Parameter Expansion
sed "s/[a-z]/'&'/g" <<< "$str"
```

### Output

```
'a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd'
```

### Check

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a version in pure Bash that also tolerates whitespace in `arr` members.

```bash
arr=(a b c d 'e f' 'g h')
aux=("${arr[@]/#/ \'}")     # add prefix " '"
aux=("${aux[@]/%/\' }")     # add suffix "' "
str="$(IFS=+                # join with "+"
       printf '%s' "${aux[*]}")"
str="${str:1:${#str} - 2}"  # trim spaces
printf '%s\n' "$str"
```